# Class method - This form of method call only allowed for class methods

Tags: class, delphi

I am creating in Delphi a class procedure (with another procedure inside it) and got this error message:

> This form of method call only allowed for class methods

Here are some code I created for testing:

```
type
  TTestClass = class
  private
    procedure PrivateProc;
  public
    class procedure PublicProc;
  end;

procedure TTestClass.PrivateProc;
begin
  ShowMessage('TestClass.PrivateProc');
end;

class procedure TTestClass.PublicProc;
begin
  PrivateProc; // ERROR: This form of method call only allowed for class methods
  ShowMessage('TestClass.PublicProc');
end;
```

**First approach**: converted the PrivateProc to a class procedure. The problem with this approach is PublicProc might have many other private procedures and functions inside it, and others inside them.

```
type
  TTestClass = class
  private
    class procedure PrivateProc;
  public
    class procedure PublicProc;
  end;

class procedure TTestClass.PrivateProc;
begin
  ShowMessage('TestClass.PrivateProc');
end;

class procedure TTestClass.PublicProc;
begin
  PrivateProc;
  ShowMessage('TestClass.PublicProc');
end;
```

**Second approach**: created the own class inside PublicProc before calling PrivateProc.

```
type
  TTestClass = class
  private
    procedure PrivateProc;
  public
    class procedure PublicProc;
  end;

procedure TTestClass.PrivateProc;
begin
  ShowMessage('TestClass.PrivateProc');
end;

class procedure TTestClass.PublicProc;
begin
  with TTestClass.Create do
  try
    PrivateProc;
  finally
    Free;
  end;
  ShowMessage('TestClass.PublicProc');
end;
```

Please, why I got this error message (can't found a reasonable explanation) and which is the best approach to solve it? Thanks!

Comment: As you already discovered, you need an object instance in order to call a non-`class` procedure. A `class` procedure does not require an object instance. Your `PublicProc` does not have access to an object instance of `TTestClass` in your first example, hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

A class procedure has no reference to the object that 'owns' it, only the class that owns it. Therefore it cannot call a procedure that needs a reference to the class that owns it, like your PrivateProc. If you make PrivateProc a class procedure, or publicProc not a class procedure, it will work.

Comment: Ok, understood. Thank you!